# Is CodeContract similar to FxCop?

Tags: c#, .net, fxcop, code-contracts

Please clarify, is the Code Contracts is similar to FxCop and StyleCop? 
As per the online references, we need to add Codes for implementing the code contract conditions inside the function of existing code.

```
public void Initialize(string name, int id)
{
    Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name));
    Contract.Requires(id > 0);
    Contract.Ensures(Name == name);
    //Do some work
}
```

Usually in FxCop, the code we want to check will be in separate Dll and the Class library which includes the rules to check will be in separate dll.
Likewise whether we can create separate class library for Code contract to rule the existing code?

Please confirm..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

disclaimer: you'd better take their current docs and read them through, write down the features and then compare them. What I wrote below is some facts I remembered long time ago about their core functionalities and I can't guarantee you that they are not outdated and now-wrong. For example, someone could write some complex&heavy rules for FxCop that behave as Contracts do. This is why I'm marking it as community-wiki. Please correct me if I'm wrong anywhere.

---

No they are not similar, although they share common target: help you find bugs.

FxCop is a "static analyzer", which inspects your code and tries to find "bad patterns". You will not see any FxCop **rules**/effects during runtime. FxCop has a set of "rules" that will be used during inspection and it reports to you whenever it finds a rule to be broken. Rules can be very easy and nitpicking like `you must initialize every variable` or `you must name classes with uppercase` or complex ones like `you shouldn't have more than one loop in a method`. Some rules are available by the standard installation, and you can expand the ruleset with your own rules.

CodeContracts is two-sided. At the most basic level, it is a set of helper methods, like `throw if argument 'foo' is null`. At runtime, when someone passes a null, it will throw. Just that simple. However, if you use those helper methods correctly and widely in your code, you will be able to run an additional static analyzer. It will scan your code, find all usages of those helper methods, and will try to automatically detect any places where their **contracts** are not satisfied. So, with the "argument is null" example, it will try to find all usages of that function, check who calls it with what args, it will try to deduce (prove) if that arg can be null at all anytime, and will warn you if it finds such case. There are more types of such validators other than just not-null, but you can't add/write your own. I mean, you could add more such helper validators, but the static analyzer wouldn't pick them up (it's too hard to write a general theorem prover for any rule).

CodeContracts is more powerful in its analyses than FxCop, but limited in diversity and scope. CodeContracts cannot check the structure of the code: it will not check the number of loops,  code complexity, names of methods, code hierarchy, etc. It can only attempt to prove/disprove some **contracts** (runtime requirements) of some methods/interfaces. FxCop on the other hand can inspect your code, style, structure, etc, but it will not "prove" or "deduce" anything - it will just check for some bad patterns defined by rules.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. Actually my question is using FxCop we can Choose our project as "Add Targets" and the Custom rules as "Add Rules" from FxCop IDE and we can analyze the tool. Can we do the same thing using Code Contracts?

Comment: @user2960882: No, because CodeContracts work in a completely different way. You can set up the analyzer to pick only some of the projects as "targets", but there is no way of specifying "custom rules". All the "rules" are built-in right into your code by the use of helper methods "Requires" "Ensures". You can't turn them on or off or you can't add/remove them without modifying your code.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. Please clarify one thing. Suppose In my project, I want to check some function say multiplication function. We need to add the Contract codes inside the existing function right. For using code contract to analyse the function whether I need to modify my existing project code with Contracts.Ensure(), Contract.Requires like that? Without modifying my project source code can we perform the Code Contract

Comment: @user2960882: No, you can't. CodeContracts **is all about** using Ensure/Requires everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for all information. Its more helpful for me :)

Answer (score 1):

While `FxCop` is used to verify some code-style or typical perfomance issues,
`Code Contracts` influences your code design, so it aims to achieve higher level goals. It's a `.NET` implementation attempt of [contract programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) methodology used in `Eiffel` language. Methodology says, that every type will behave correctly (performing its postconditions and invariants), only if it will have input according to required preconditions.

You should describe your types preconditions, invariants and postconditions  with use of library helper methods and attributes (`Contract.Requires`, etc.) and `Code Contracts` static analizer will be able to detect their failures during compilation.

(Last time I looked at it, tool was rather slow and hard to use. Seems, that it haven't been completed by microsoft research team. Fortunately, few days ago a [new version](https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts/releases/tag/v1.9.10714.2) of it have been released with bug-fixes for `async-await` as well as VS2015 support.)

Comment: Thanks for your response.. Please clarify one thing. Suppose In my project, I want to check some function say multiplication function. We need to add the Contract codes inside the existing function right. For using code contract to analyse the function whether I need to modify my existing project code with Contracts.Ensure(), Contract.Requires like that? Without modifying my project source code can we perform the Code Contract ?

Comment: Contract is a part of your code, that's the thing. So, no, you cannot verify anything without using guards from Contract class for contract description.

Comment: @Vladislav I'm still trying to figure out where the "code contract static analyzer" is...